# How to read specific line value with argument using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have a file with this format.

```
English
Name
    Gerry
Class
    Elementry
ID Number
    0812RX
Gender
    *Male
     Female
Address
     St.Joseph Rd.78
Member Name
     Jack
```

The structure of this file is, the value of `Name`, there is one `enter` and  one `tab` and then the value `Gerry`

I want to read the value of the each item. 
I tried this code.

```
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath, $Key
)

$FileContent = Get-Content $FilePath | Where-Object{"^($Key)","`$1$Value"}
$FileContent
```

My expectation, when I execute this command

```
powershell.ps1 -FilePath file.txt -Key Name
```

It will return : `Gerry`

Please, anyone give me idea. Thanks

Comment: The file does not look like a standardized structure. You will have to parse it yourself. Where do you get this file? Is the program/process you get this file from able to provide the data in a standardized file format like CSV, JSON or XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to use the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) with the `-File` parameter:

```
$found = $false
$value = switch -File file.txt {
  'Name' { $found = $true }
  default { if ($found) { $_.Substring(1); break } }
}
```

With your sample input, `$value` should then contain `Gerry`.

`$found` is set to `$true` once `'Name'` is found on a line of its own; in the `default` block, which is executed for all other line, the following line is then returned, stripped of its initial (tab) char.

Wrapped in a script with parameters, simulated here with a script block for brevity:

```
# Create a sample file; "`t" creates a tab char.
@"
Name
`tGerry
Class
`tElementary
ID Number
`t0812RX
"@ > file.txt

# Script block that simulates a script file.
& {

  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $FilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Key
  )

  $found = $false
  switch -File $FilePath { 
    $Key { $found = $true }
    default { if ($found) { return $_.Substring(1) } }
  }

} -FilePath file.txt -Key Name
```

The above yields `Gerry`.

Note that if your key name has spaces, you must pass it *quoted* to the script; e.g.:

```
... -FilePath file.txt  -Key 'ID Number'
```

Comment: one more question please, I would like to set the value as a variable, I tried this `$GetValue = switch -File $FilePath {$Key { $found = $true } default { if ($found) { return $_.Substring(1) } }}
  $test = $GetValue + "ok"
  $test` but I cant get the value @mklementO

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Get-Content`, the file is ingested as an array of strings that you can reference.

This assumes your files have a consistent format - that they have the same number of lines, and the lines correspond to the fields as you've specified in your sample. If not, it's possible to do something with regexes, but we won't get into that now.

```
$file = (get-content c:\temp\myfile.txt).trim()
$lang = $file[0]
$name = $file[3]
$class = $file[5]
$idNo = $file[7]
if ($file[9] -match '`*') {$gender = "Male"}
if ($file[10] -match '`*') {$gender = "Female"}
$address = $file[12]
```

You can then assign the values you've captured to a PSCustomObject or hashtable. In fact, it's easiest to just do it at the same time.

```
$student= [PsCustomObject]@{
    Lang = $file[0]
    Name = $file[3]
    Class = $file[5]
    ...
}
```

I'll leave outputting the object attributes in the manner you've described as an exercise for your own enjoyment!

Comment: I dont want to identify it by giving the index number because the position sometime different.